# Writing infinite bash loop

Tags: linux, bash

How to write an infinite loop echoing numbers from 1 to infinite in bash.
I am using a for loop but it is being killed by bash on using value more than 100000000.

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in {1..100000000..1}
do
  echo "$a"
done
```

any alternative for it?

Comment: With the brace expansion form, bash has to expand `{1..100000000..1}` **first**, before starting the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work in all POSIX shells:

```
i=0; while :; do echo "$((i+=1))"; done
```

`:` is interchangeable with the `true` builtin (which you can use instead): it's a no-op that always succeeds (=returns 0).

If integer overflow bothers you, and you want arbitrary precision with standard tools:

```
nocontinuation(){ sed ':x; /\\$/ { N; s/\\\n//; tx }'; }
i=99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
while : ; do i=`echo "$i + 1" | bc | nocontinuation`; echo "$i"; done
```

This would be quite slow, because it spawns in each iteration.
To avoid that, you could reuse one `bc` instance and communicate with it over pipes:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -e
nocontinuation(){ sed -u ':x; /\\$/ { N; s/\\\n//; tx }'; }
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' exit
tmpdir=`mktemp -d`
cd "$tmpdir"
mkfifo p n 
<p bc | nocontinuation >n &
exec 3>p
exec 4<n

i=99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
while : ; do 
  echo "$i + 1" >&3
  read i <&4
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: `$((i++))` will work in any POSIX shell; it's not an extension.

Comment: @chepner `$((i++))` doesn't work in dash, but I noticed ` $((i+=1))` does and is documented. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't look closely at what was *in* the arithmetic expression, only that `expr` is almost never necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried doing a `while` loop?

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0;

while :
do
    num=$((num+1))
    echo "$num"
done
```

Comment: Please remove the spaces around `=` and in your example you don't have `$a`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a `while true;`?

```
a=0
while true;
do
    a=$((a+1))
    # $[$a+1] also works.
    echo "$a"
done
```

Comment: I'd upvote this, but you're using the undocumented `$[...]` arithmetic expression syntax.

Comment: Beware that the counter will eventually overflow.